# Logs Explorer not showing full logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, audit-logging

I am currently looking to generate a list of buckets together with their metadata within my org and merge them with a field from audit logging. The field that I am interested in is the resource creator, to identify the accounts used to create the buckets.

First, to get the full list of buckets within my org as well as their metadata, I:

1. gcloud projects list - to get the full list of projects within my org
2. gcloud config set project {project_id} + for loop - to set project Id and run the subsequent lines project-by-project
3. gcloud storage ls - to obtain the list of buckets within individual projects
4. gcloud storage buckets describe {bucket_id} - to obtain more details pertaining to the bucket
5. Write into a local csv file.

Now for finding the creator field, I thought of running:

1. gcloud logging read "resource.type=gcs_bucket AND
   protoPayload.methodName="storage.buckets.create" - this by right should get me more data than I need for my work, since I only need the "creator" field.
2. Perform join on the two tables

Now the problem is the "gcloud logging read" line does not output anything when running on Google cloud CLI. Later I saw from another SO post that freshness parameter must be included, so I added --freshness=360d and now the cli just takes forever to run.

Curiously, I did the same query on Logs Explorer console and found that the number of buckets creation actions performed in the past did not tally with the number of buckets found in my bucket list.

Since I could see some logs in Logs Explorer, I believe this shouldn't be a permissioning issue.

What have I possibly done wrong?

Comment: Can you let me know whether you are trying to find who created the buckets and group them logically?

Comment: If a bucket was created 3 years ago as an example. Logs might not catch it... did you investigate that scenario?

Comment: @danyL I am just going to extract whatever Audit Log still has and do a join later on. Even the recently created buckets (created this year) cant be found in our Logs Explorer..

Comment: @Srividya Thanks for being willing to help! I am just looking to find who created the buckets. Don't need to group them logically or perform any other actions as of now. Just the raw data will do.

Answer (score 0):

The following command did not work for me

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gcs_bucket AND protoPayload.methodName="storage.buckets.create"
```

Try

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gcs_bucket AND protoPayload.methodName=storage.buckets.create"
```

" was removed before storage